# CakePHP IntegrationTestTrait Post Returns HTTP Status 302

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am trying to perform a simple test from posting data onto a table in CakePHP. I am using IntegrationTestTrait.

I am not able to POST data successfully. My `$this->_response` is yielding:

```
object(Cake\Http\Response) {

    'status' => (int) 302,
    'contentType' => 'text/html',
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => [
            (int) 0 => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        ],
        'Location' => [
            (int) 0 => '/'
        ]
    ],
    'file' => null,
    'fileRange' => [],
    'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection) {
        [protected] cookies => []
    },
    'cacheDirectives' => [],
    'body' => ''

}
```

My TestCase code looks like this:

```
    public function testAddStudentSuccess() {

        $data = [
        'last_name' => 'Test',
        'first_name' => '05',
        'middle_name' => '',
        'preferred_name' => '',
        'id_number' => '10005',
        'contact_id' => '',
        'users[0][email]' => 'test_05@email.com'
        ];

        //Test Pre-condition 
        $query = $this->Students->find('all')->where([
            'id_number' => $data['id_number']
        ]); 

        $this->post('/students/add', $data); 

        debug($this->_response);
    }
```

- I debugged further and found that the Test is not even invoking the Controller add() functions.

I thought the issue was an Authentication Issue is I tried following all the authentication work arounds prescribed in the documentation. However, it did not work.

Does anyone know how I can debug this further? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty standard procedure to redirect (302) somewhere after accepting and saving posted data. Are you sure that's not what's happening here?

Comment: When I query the Fixture, the data did not save successfully.

Comment: Could it be because you're using the `get` function when you're trying to post data?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo, I forgot to correct during testing.

Comment: Set a breakpoint (or add debug output) in [**`\Cake\Http\Response::withLocation()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.8.6/src/Http/Response.php#L801-L818) (or `location()` depending on your CakePHP version) and inspect the stacktrace to figure out from where exactly the redirect is being initiated.

Comment: Okay, there is a call to the CORE Authentication function. So once again it appears to be an authentication issue.